# aws dynamodb import/export JSON format

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, export, importerror

I have exported JSON files from aws dynamodb in this format:

```
[
  {
    "__typename": "Article",
<snip>
  }
<snip>
]
```

This results in "Invalid JSON" error:

```
aws dynamodb batch-write-item --request-items file://Article.json

Error parsing parameter '--request-items': Invalid JSON:
```

The correct format is (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SampleData.LoadData.html)
How to export the DynamoDB so that I could easily import it to tables? Or is there anything I could do to transform the JSON files that I receive from third party?

Answer (score 1):

The json seems to be invalid. you could use https://jsonlint.com/ to validate the JSON.

A sample valid JSON messages are available at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/samples/sampledata.zip

To import data to DynamoDB Table

```
aws dynamodb batch-write-item --request-items file://ProductCatalog.json
{
    "UnprocessedItems": {}
}
```

you could export data from DynamoDB using the following command

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name ProductCatalog > ProductCatalog_export.json
```

DynamoDB can import data in three formats: CSV, DynamoDB JSON, and Amazon Ion.

- CSV
- DynamoDB Json
- Amazon Ion

More information at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/S3DataImport.Format.html